# Overloading function types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

#### Problem

I have this type definition:

```
export type StringOrErrorCallback = (error: ?Error, result: string) => void;
```

`error` is obviously nullable.

However, I want `result` to exist only when `error` is not truthy.

If I do this:

```
export type StringOrErrorCallback = (error: ?Error, result?: string) => void;
```

I make `result` optional, so it's all fine for the caller of this function, but the users will need to check not only the `error` argument, but also the `result` argument.

#### Examples

```
//user
function doSomething(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  // it's a given that "result" exists at this point
}

//caller (both lines should be valid)
doSomething(new Error('something happened'));
doSomething(null, 'resulting string');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly think it's a good solution (though it does work), but I just found out how they do it internally for the native functions.

```
export type ResultOrErrorCallback = (error: ?Error, result: any) => void;

function doSomething(error, result: string) {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  // it's a given that "result" exists at this point
}

doSomething(new Error('something happened'));
doSomething(null, 'resulting string');
```

I don't think it can be done properly at this point, but maybe someone out there has some good ideas...